# Facebook open graph changed my https link to http when I post to timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, https, facebook-opengraph

I would like to post an Open graph object to Facebook. Every link is HTTPS but after post to Facebook, it shows error:

This story was invalidated because: The object at [http://minifacebook.co.kr/music/post_open_graph?fb_source=profile_multiline&fb_action_types=listenns%3Alisten&fb_action_ids=181400501941476] doesn't have a title.

It seems FB changed HTTPS protocol to HTTP. I posted following link:

[https://minifacebook.co.kr/music/post_open_graph]

Moreover, I used [http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug] to test above link. They show different results when I use https://minifacebook.co.kr/music/post_open_graph and http://minifacebook.co.kr/music/post_open_graph

Is there any clues?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was solved after I tried many ways crazily. You have to add sign "/" (slash) after your link like following:
https://minifacebook.co.kr/music/post_open_graph/

It works!

Comment: Sorry, I checked again. If you add "/", FB detects as root domain. You have to add a fake parameter like that: https://minifacebook.co.kr/music/post_open_graph?a=1